# Llenar un Dropdownlist con un precedimiento almacenado en MVC

Tags: mvc

Quiero llenar un dropdwonlist con un procedimiento almacenado.

Mi procedimiento es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDepartamentos
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT 0 Id_Departamento, 'Todos'  Nombre_Departamento
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Id_Departamento, Nombre_Departamento FROM Departamentos
END
```

Ya he mapeado mi procedimiento con entityframework y me creo un modelo `GetDepartamentos_Result.cs`

Ahora en mi controlador tengo un metodo que retorna una Lista:

```
public List<GetDepartamentos_Result> GetDepartamentos()
    {
        using (TigerEntities db = new TigerEntities())
        {
            var v = db.GetDepartamentos().ToList();
            return v;
        }
    }
```

Y un método ActionResult combo que me envia a mi vista `Combo.cshtml`:

```
public ActionResult Combo()
    {
        var a = GetDepartamentos();
        ViewBag.Departamentos  = new SelectList(a, "Id_Departamento", "Nombre_Departamento");
        return View();
    }
```

Es correcto lo que estoy haciendo para llenar el combo?
No he logrado conseguirlo y ademas como lo llamaria en vista?

@model List

Espero me puedan alguna orientacion al respecto.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la vista podrías hacer:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departamentos")
```

En caso quieres tenerlo relacionado a un `Model`podrías hacer:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id_Departamento, ViewBag.Departamentos as SelectList)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La primera opción me funciona muy bien, sin embargo en la segunda opción si lo quiero relacionar con mi modelo no funciona. Hago referencia al modelo pero no me muestra las propiedades: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id_Departamento, ViewBag.Departamentos as SelectList)

model.Id_Departamento me marca error, tal ves pueda ser por que en la vista al relacionarla con un modelo le indico que es una lista?

Comment: @model List<WebgridPagingSortingFiltering.GetDepartamentos_Result>

Comment: Lo deje sin el List<> y funciona perfecto. Pero sigo sin entender por que si le pongo List<> ya no me funciona. Se supone que le estoy pasando una Lista al combo no?

Comment: @Luis Por lo general cuando referencias en la vista `@model List<T>` es para mostrar un listado en la vista (ejem: Index), por ejemplo, si quieres mostrar en la vista el listado de departamentos y recorrerla. Ahora, si quieres mostrar solo un objecto (en tu caso `GetDepartamentos_Result`) deberías usar `@model T` que se usa más que todo para mostrar el detalle de tu lista  en una vista (ejem: Create, Edit, Details). Recuerda que cuando digo `T` me refiero a un tipo genérico, en tu caso para el tipo clase `GetDepartamentos_Result`.

Comment: @Luis no olvides revisar: [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Davlio por aclararme la duda, ahora lo entiendo mejor gracias a ti. Y pues gracias por orientarme también acerca de como aceptar la respuesta, la verdad era la primera vez que entro al foro y no sabia que tenia que marcar la palomita para aceptarka jejeje. Nuevamente muchísimas gracias por tu apoyo y espero no sea molestia seguirte preguntando dudas que me vallan saliendo en el transcurso. Tendría que hacer otra pregunta es correcto?

Comment: @Luis dale, ese es el propósito del sitio.

Comment: Hola mi esttimado Davlio, nuenvamente aqui molestandote con una duda, ya llevo algo hecho sin embargo quisiera me puediras orientar en como pasar a mi controlador el dato seleccionado en el dropdownlist. Cabe resaltar que tengo otro procedimiento almacenado que cargara los datos en el grid dependiento la opcion seleccionada en el drop.

Comment: Ya tengo mapeado mi otro procedimiento (SearchEmployeesDropDown_Result). Ahora por lo que tengo entendido no se puede tener dos modelos en una vista por lo que he generado una clase que contenga mis dos modelos (GetDepartamentos_Result y SearchEmployeesDropDown_Result).

Comment: public class ViewModels
    {
        public GetDepartamentos_Result Combo { get; set; }
        public List<SearchEmployeesDropDown_Result> Grid { get; set; }
    }

Comment: En el controlador Ya tengo mis dos metodos uno para cargar el combo y otro para mostrar el grid.

Comment: No he logrado enviar a mi controlador el valor del combo que seleccione. En la vista hago esto: @model WebgridPagingSortingFiltering.Models.ViewModels

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("combo", "home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Combo.Nombre_Departamento, ViewBag.Departamentos as SelectList)
                            @*<input type="text" name="search" value="@ViewBag.search" class="form-control" placeholder="search" />*@
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
                    }

Comment: Disculpa que ponga el codigo aqui en los comentarios pero no se como ponerlo para que aparezca como cuando formule la pregunta.